# Getting a portion of a sorted array from start value to end value

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript and I need to get a portion (slice) of a sorted array (Numbers, timestamps basically) by start_value and end_value.

For example, let's say I have an array of random timestamps from last month, and I want to get all timestamps between two weeks ago and a week ago.
This is a pretty simple algorithm to write (using a binary search) but I don't want to mess up my code with these computations.
I've been searching for a way to do this in javascript but haven't found any.

Thanks for any future help :)

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: If it's sorted, you could use `indexOf()` to find the start and end indexes, then just call `slice()` with those. You could even being the end index search at 1 past the returned start index to speed it up.

Comment: @skyline3000 Using `indexOf` assumes there are exact matches for `start_value` and `end_value` in the array. For the dates example given there might not be a timestamp for the exact time of 'one week ago'.

Comment: If you wanted to go down the route of finding the index you could maybe use `findIndex`, though that still isn't a binary search and it isn't supported by IE.

Comment: yes, indexOf is not what I need since it requires exact matches. btw I forgot to mention I'm using es6, so maybe anything from there?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use `filter`?

```js
var dates = [123, 234, 456, 468, 568, 678];
var min = 300;
var max = 500;

var inRange = dates.filter(function(date) {
    return min < date && date < max;
});

console.log(inRange);
```

On the plus side, this doesn't even need them to be sorted. On the down side, it probably won't be as fast as a well-implemented binary search for the relevant start and end points. Unless you've got some really harsh performance requirements I don't think that'll matter.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The array can be pretty big and it's a UI component, so doing an O(n) over O(log-n) is not really an option.

Comment: How big are we talking?

Comment: @OrelCohen OK, 10M does sound like it'd be enough to make using `filter` impractical. Generally I wouldn't want the UI to have all 10M in memory in the first place. Even if the memory usage isn't a concern the data transfer between the server and UI would likely be unacceptably slow. Once you've taken a 'one week' slice the operations you then perform on it would likely also be too slow. If all that isn't a problem then I think you do need a binary search. If you can't find a third-party library you trust then you can justify writing the code because of your extreme performance requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a pure js library called binarysearch that has exactly what I'm looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/binarysearch. It has rangeValue function which accepts non-existing numbers as start-end. Seems to be working :)